# Visual Studio 2008 CE 7.0 Platform

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am trying to build a program that targets `WT41N0c70PSDK (ARMv4I)` in Visual Studio 2008. However, when I open the solution, I receive the following error

[image]

I am running Windows 10. I have installed SP1 for VS 2008. I have also installed the CE 7.0 update from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11935). However, VS 2008 is missing the WT41N0c70PSDK platform. Am I missing some SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need an SDK to develop for a specific platform, those come as MSI files that you have to install after you set-up Visual Studio.
If that SDK references a specific device, then probably the manufacture could provide you the right SDK.